# Image is not being shown in HTML

Tags: html, laravel, filesystems

I am trying to save images in Laravel which is working perfectly fine but I am facing errors while trying to retrieve the images and displaying them in HTML

In my controller I have this method when I am implementing the logic for saving the data, I am saving the images in images disk
This method is working fine it is saving the book in the database and the image in the images folder

```
public function storeImage(StoreBookRequest $request) {    
    $validated = $request->validated();
    $coverImage = $request->file('bookcover');
    $extension = $coverImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
    Storage::disk('images')->put($coverImage->getFilename() . '.' . $extension,File::get($coverImage));
    $book = Book::create([
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'author' => $request->get('author'),
        'mime' => $coverImage->getClientMimeType(),
        'original_filename' => $coverImage->getFilename().'.'.$extension
    ]);

    return redirect()->route('home')
        ->with('success','Book added successfully...');
    }
```

But when I am trying to retrieve the image

```
public function displayImage(Book $book) {
    return view('displayBook',compact('book'));
}
```

In the display book blade, I am calling it this way but without success because the image is not being shown.
What can be the problem

```
<body>
    <h2>Image</h2>
    <img src="{{'storage/app/public/images/' .$book->original_filename}}" alt="profile Pic" height="200" width="200">
</body>
```

The path from the content root of a saved image example

```
public/storage/images/php6A51.tmp.png
```

`fileSystem.php` which I have added the images Disk

```
'images' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
    'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
    'visibility' => 'public',
],
```

Comment: Probably you are missing a `/` at the begin `/storage/app/public/images/`

Comment: try to use the asset helper like: `{{asset('storage/images/' .$book->original_filename')}}`
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-asset
and I think your src url is wrong it does not match the path you wrote in the last place @Thymeleaf

Comment: @Espresso still not working :(

Comment: @Aless55 that did not work either .

Comment: did you create the sys link so that the images are available?

Comment: Yeah i have created disk images in the filesystem.php and i have run php artisan link.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't hard code storage urls. This is correct way of getting urls:

```php
    Storage::disk('images')->url('filename');
```

This is my images disk in filesystems.php:

```php
...
        'images' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/public/images'),
            'url' => '/storage/images',
            'visibility' => 'public',
        ],
```

and img tag is:

```html
<img src="{{Storage::disk('images')->url('filename')}}" width="50" height="60">
```

I have removed env('APP_URL') from image disk url value. This gives relative path.